# How can i check token reflection amount for wallet address?

Tags: blockchain, dapp-development

I am learning about blockchain and trying to figure out how to get all inflows of token to my wallet.

Can find all inbound wallet transactions for specific token, but i can't find inflows of reflections. I understood that reflections are not represented as transactions.

What should i look for? Events, logs, receipts?

UPDATE: this link explains well that there is no actual transfer but there is calculation done by contract to include reflections when you invoke balanceOf. I still miss how to get calculation formula.

Comment: simply your balance

Comment: @AdamBoudjemaa thanks, yet question is how to get all inflows, not sum of all inflows which would be current balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since I know you are talking about safemoon... it's your balance. The full answer is located in the transfer functions of that contract. Be warned though... it's kind of a mess and it could be cleaner imo.

Comment: Thanks, i am looking into some other token but transfers implementation is quite similar. Still don't see where I can find reflections in chain. I want to be able to recalculate balance for each day in the history hence need both transaction amounts and reflections.

Comment: There is no "reflections" function because it all gets handled in before/after functions for for transfer. (See ERC20.sol) Like I said, that contract is a mess. (It's also been a while so I may be recalling this incorrectly)